# I want to remove this Login and SignUp link once one of them is been selected in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, router

Here is my APP.JS code and I want to remove this Login and SignUp link once this is being selected to open the components.

```
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
     
     
     <Router>
     <Link to="/login"><h1>Login</h1></Link>
     <Link to="/signup"><h1>SignUp</h1></Link>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by selected?
like once a user navigated to one of above links?

Comment: yes , once these links is clicked  then i dont want them to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

....inside component....
const location = useLocation();

return (
<div className="App">
 
 
 <Router>
 { location.pathname !== '/login' && location.pathname !== '/signup' ? <>
 <Link to="/login"><h1>Login</h1></Link>
 <Link to="/signup"><h1>SignUp</h1></Link>
 </> : null }
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
    <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
 </div>
```

this will do the trick

Comment: still not working - am I declaring "location " correctly:
export default function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  
  return (
//code//
}

please check

Comment: still not working - am I declaring "location " correctly ???
<code> export default function App() { const location = useLocation(); return (  </code> please check

Comment: try adding '/' to the pathnames in the if blocks

location.pathname !== '/login' && location.pathname !== '/signup'

Comment: its not cleared to me

Comment: can you please rewrite the code